# Node/Express.js - Overriding where to look for the 'Views' folder for each request

Tags: node.js, express

In my Node/Express.js project I can set the views folder globally like so:

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    .... snip ....
});
```

...and all my view templates go into the views folder.

**Is it possible to override where Express looks for views on a request by request basis?** For instance, something like the following:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { viewFolder: 'otherViews' });
});
```

The reason I ask is I'm trying to replicate Microsoft ASP.NET MVC's Areas functionality where each Area gets it's own views folder.

Comment: hi did you ever find a better solution to the accepted answer? where the areas don't have to be a sub folder of the views folder?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The 'views' setting is the root directory, so you should be able to specify a sub-folder in the hierarchy:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('areaName/viewName');
});
```

It means your 'areas' need to be sub-folders, but it allows you to accomplish the separation you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

As a more modular solution, I did something like this in sails.js.
Just over-ride the render function for the given request in your middleware. :)

```
var curRender = res.render;
res.render = function(path, locals, func) {
    var args = [res.locals.explicitPath + '/' + path, locals, func];
    curRender.apply(this, args);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Full path works too

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render(path.join(__dirname, 'view.jade'));
});
```