# Multiple view paths in Express (node.js)

Tags: node.js, express

I'm writing a CMS on **Node.js with Express Framework**. On my CMS I have several modules for users, pages, etc.

I want that each module will have his files on **separate folder**, **including the view files**. 
Anyone know how can I achieve that?

I'm using **swig** as my template engine but I can replace it to something else if it will helps.

Comment: Would something like this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470466/node-express-js-overriding-where-to-look-for-the-views-folder-for-each-reque

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374424/mean-app-with-admin-panel-and-client-panel?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Last Update**

*The multiple view folders feature is supported by the framework since Express 4.10*

Just pass an array of locations to the `views` property, like so.

```
app.set('views', [__dirname + '/viewsFolder1', __dirname + '/viewsFolder2']);
```

**Express 2.0**

As far as I know express doesn't support multiple view paths or namespaces at the moment (like the static middleware do)

But you can modify the lookup logic yourself so that it works the way you want, for example:

```
function enableMultipleViewFolders(express) {
    // proxy function to the default view lookup
    var lookupProxy = express.view.lookup;

    express.view.lookup = function (view, options) {
        if (options.root instanceof Array) {
            // clones the options object
            var opts = {};
            for (var key in options) opts[key] = options[key];

            // loops through the paths and tries to match the view
            var matchedView = null,
                roots = opts.root;
            for (var i=0; i<roots.length; i++) {
                opts.root = roots[i];
                matchedView = lookupProxy.call(this, view, opts);
                if (matchedView.exists) break;
            }
            return matchedView;
        }

        return lookupProxy.call(express.view, view, options)
    };
}
```

You will enable the new logic by calling the function above and passing *express* as a parameter, and then you will be able to specify an array of views to the configuration:

```
var express = require('express');
enableMultipleViewFolders(express);
app.set('views', [__dirname + '/viewsFolder1', __dirname + '/viewsFolder2']);
```

Or, if you prefer, you can patch the framework directly (updating the *view.js* file inside it)

This should **work in Express 2.x**, not sure if it will with the new version (3.x)

**UPDATE**

Unluckily the above solution won't work in Express 3.x since *express.view* would be *undefined*

Another possible solution will be to proxy the *response.render* function and set the views folder config until it gets a match:

```
var renderProxy = express.response.render;
express.render = function(){
    app.set('views', 'path/to/custom/views');
    try {
        return renderProxy.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    catch (e) {}
    app.set('views', 'path/to/default/views');       
    return renderProxy.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

I've not tested it, it feels very hacky to me anyway, unluckily this feature has been pushed back again:
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/pull/1186

**UPDATE 2**

This feature has been added in Express 4.10, since the following pull request has been merged:
https://github.com/strongloop/express/pull/2320

Comment: There isn't any talk about implementing this in 3.x so your function should work in the new version.

Comment: Yeah it seems so, but some (many?) APIs in 3.x changed, and I think it was refactored, it doesn't seem they changed the view.js file too much lately: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/commits/master/lib/view.js It will probably work, I'll test it when I've got some spare time

Comment: I have made this into a module that works for Express 4.x. https://www.npmjs.org/package/multi-views

Comment: @Feng - It does not seem to be apparent from the [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html). It only says that `views` is set to a single directory. Can you please point me to a place and docs or in the code where it supports multiple directories?

Comment: @VagmiMudumbai just noticed that this is added just a couple of days ago, landed in 4.10 not 4.x https://github.com/strongloop/express/pull/2320

Comment: I got this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'lookup' of undefined
` how I can fix?

Comment: I have express `4.16.2` and when I pass an array `app.set('views', [__dirname + '/viewsFolder1', __dirname + '/viewsFolder2']);` I still get `TypeError: Path must be a string.`

Comment: @VagmiMudumbai in the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.settings.table) for the `.set('views',..)` in versions `4.x` it says that "views" shall take "A directory or an array of directories for the application's views. If an array, the views are looked up in the order they occur in the array."

Comment: Hi everyone, I have question. I have 2 views directories. So Can I create layout.ejs file in each them ?  one directory one layout.ejs . can I do it ?

Comment: Hey @BFil, I am using your first solution as I'm using express version `4.16.0` and `express-handlebars`. I'm getting the following error: `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "from" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array`. could you help me pls

Comment: It looks like a compatibility issue with express-handlebars: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3976

Answer (score 11):

In addition to @user85461 answer, the require view part did not work for me. 
What i did: removed the path stuff and moved it all to a module i could require,
patch.ViewEnableMultiFolders.js (Works with current express):

```
function ViewEnableMultiFolders(app) {
    // Monkey-patch express to accept multiple paths for looking up views.
    // this path may change depending on your setup.
    var lookup_proxy = app.get('view').prototype.lookup;

    app.get('view').prototype.lookup = function(viewName) {
        var context, match;
        if (this.root instanceof Array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.root.length; i++) {
                context = {root: this.root[i]};
                match = lookup_proxy.call(context, viewName);
                if (match) {
                    return match;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        return lookup_proxy.call(this, viewName);
    };
}

module.exports.ViewEnableMultiFolders = ViewEnableMultiFolders;
```

and used:

```
var Patch = require('patch.ViewEnableMultiFolders.js');
Patch.ViewEnableMultiFolders(app);
app.set('views', ['./htdocs/views', '/htdocs/tpls']);
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution for Express 3.x.  It monkey-patches express 3.x's "View" object to do the same lookup trick as @ShadowCloud's solution above.  Unfortunately, the path lookup for the `View` object is less clean, since 3.x doesn't expose it to `express` -- so you have to dig into the bowels of node_modules.

```
function enable_multiple_view_folders() {
    // Monkey-patch express to accept multiple paths for looking up views.
    // this path may change depending on your setup.
    var View = require("./node_modules/express/lib/view"),
        lookup_proxy = View.prototype.lookup;

    View.prototype.lookup = function(viewName) {
        var context, match;
        if (this.root instanceof Array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.root.length; i++) {
                context = {root: this.root[i]};
                match = lookup_proxy.call(context, viewName);
                if (match) {
                    return match;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        return lookup_proxy.call(this, viewName);
    };
}

enable_multiple_view_folders();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can however, put all the view files inside the 'view' folder, but separate each module's view into it's own folders inside the 'view' folder. So, the structure is something like this :

```
views  
--moduleA    
--moduleB  
----submoduleB1  
----submoduleB2  
--moduleC
```

Set the view files like usual :

```
app.set('views', './views');
```

And when render for each module, include the module's name :

```
res.render('moduleA/index', ...);
```

or even submodule's name :

```
res.render('moduleB/submoduleB1/index', ...);
```

This solution is also works in express before version 4.x,

Answer (score 1):

Install glob `npm install glob`

If you have a `views` directory that looks something like:

```
views
├── 404.ejs
├── home.ejs
├── includes
│   ├── header.ejs
│   └── footer.ejs
├── post
│   ├── create.ejs
│   └── edit.ejs
└── profile.ejs
```

You can use this glob function to return an array of subdirectories in the `views` directory (add the `path.substring` to remove the trailing `/`)

```
let viewPaths = glob.sync('views/**/').map(path => {
    return path.substring(0, path.length - 1)
})


console.log(viewPaths)
>> ['views', 'views/post', 'views/includes']
```

So now you can set

```
app.set('views', viewPaths)
```

and now you can use

```
res.render('404')
res.render('home')
res.render('post/edit')
res.render('post/create')
```

Answer (score 0):

For all the people who are still looking for the answer. Mention the paths in an array.
ex:

```
app.set('views', [
path.join(path.resolve(), 'src', 'features', 'user', 'views'),
path.join(path.resolve(), 'src', 'features', 'home', 'view')]);
```