# Look up layouts and include files on multiple paths in express/ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am building a node application based on express using ejs as template engine.

To support different looks for the site I would like to put files in folders named base holding vanilla stuff and an overlay per style/theme/client. I want the system to lookup files in overlay first, and only if not found use what is in base.

For static content like images and css files this works using the static middleware twice, first for the overlay, then for base.

I want to do the same for templates rendered through ejs. I have found:

[Multiple View paths on Node.js + Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315351/multiple-view-paths-on-node-js-express?lq=1)

And BananaAcids answer provided in that thread almost works for me as long as I call simple ejs views. If I want to use layouts or includes it breaks down for overlaid views because the base directory is now overlay and layouts that are unchanged from base are no longer found.

A simplified example follows.

File base/layouts/root.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <!-- Main content of pages using this layout goes here -->
    <%- body %>
  </body>
</html>
```

File base/index.ejs:

```
<% layout('layouts/root') -%>
<p>
    A page in base using the root layout
</p>
```

File overlay/index.ejs:

```
<% layout('layouts/root') -%>
<p>
    Totally different page in the overlay.
</p>
```

Using BananaAcids approach and setting both paths as view-sources express/ejs now correctly locates overlay/index.ejs as the view to render but as I did not also overlay layouts/root it fails because the resulting file overlay/layouts/root.ejs does not exist.

Is there a way of patching my way further down into ejs so that I can help it locate this file in base/layout/root.ejs instead?

Thank you for reading this and any brain cycles you have expended on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've used to monkey patch Express (4.x) to add layout support:

```
/*
   Usage:
     Set a global/default layout with:
        app.set('view layout', 'foo');
     Set a layout per-render (overrides global layout) with:
        res.render('foo', { layout: 'bar' });
     Or disable a layout if a global layout is set with:
        res.render('foo', { layout: false });
     If no layout is provided using either of the above methods,
     then the view will be rendered as-is like normal.

     Inside your layout, the variable `body` holds the rendered partial/child view.

   Installation:
     Call `mpResponse();` before doing `require('express');` in your application.
*/

function mpResponse() {
  var expressResponse = require('express/lib/response'),
      expressResRender = expressResponse.render;
  expressResponse.render = function(view, options, fn) {
    options = options || {};
    var self = this,
        req = this.req,
        app = req.app,
        layout,
        cb;

    // support callback function as second arg
    if (typeof options === 'function')
      fn = options, options = {};

    // merge res.locals
    options._locals = self.locals;

    // default callback to respond
    fn = fn || function(err, str) {
      if (err) return req.next(err);
      self.send(str);
    };

    if (typeof options.layout === 'string')
      layout = options.layout;
    else if (options.layout !== false
             && typeof app.get('view layout') === 'string')
      layout = app.get('view layout');

    if (layout) {
      cb = function(err, str) {
        if (err) return req.next(err);
        options.body = str;
        expressResRender.call(self, layout, options, fn);
      };
    } else
      cb = fn;

    // render
    app.render(view, options, cb);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I patched EJS to support the multiple views folder feature added in Express v.4.10. There is currently a pending pull request you can find here: https://github.com/mde/ejs/pull/120. If you still need this solution for your project you could include my fork into your package.json as a EJS replacement:

`{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
     "ejs": "git://github.com/MarcelloDiSimone/ejs.git#feature/multi-views"
  }
}`

..or you plus one the pull request and hope it'll be accepted soon.