# Add more view folder for Jade files in EXPRESS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I know that this line `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` in Express set view variable so i can render all my .jade files in ./views folder.

Does anyone know how to add more value to views variable, so i can render my .jade file outside ./views folder and also those inside ./views folder ?

(eg. ./includes/form/form.jade and ./views/index.jade )

I have Express 4.2.0, with files structured like this :

```
+ node_modules
+ public
    - includes
        - form
            - index.jade
            - style.less
            - script-form.js
+ views
    - index.jade
```

Comment: I've editted my answer what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This was working for me because I have express 3.x or upper version.

```
function enable_multiple_view_folders() {
// Monkey-patch express to accept multiple paths for looking up views.
// this path may change depending on your setup.
var View = require("./node_modules/express/lib/view"),
    lookup_proxy = View.prototype.lookup;

View.prototype.lookup = function(viewName) {
    var context, match;
    if (this.root instanceof Array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.root.length; i++) {
            context = {root: this.root[i]};
            match = lookup_proxy.call(context, viewName);
            if (match) {
                return match;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    return lookup_proxy.call(this, viewName);
};
```

}

and use it like:-

```
enable_multiple_view_folders();
app.set('views', [__dirname + '/views', __dirname + '/form']);
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Comment: i wants to build a plugin system for my web-app so every plugins contributors can put their .less, .js, .jade in just one folder. The system will read those files and handle its integration. So i need to know how to include .jade file outside ./views folder. Is it possible ?

Comment: You can refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315351/multiple-view-paths-on-node-js-express. I went here tried multiple things and above worked for me

Comment: thx for reply, i tried to make this solution works with no results. the enable_multiple_view_folders works but only if i swapped my `app.set('views', [__dirname + '/views', __dirname + '/public/includes/form']);`  to `app.set('views', [__dirname + '/public/includes/form', __dirname + '/views']);`. It's seems that express just search for file in the first directory name supplied, if it doesn't exists in first directory then it throws an error `ENOENT, no such file or directory`