# TypeError: Cannot read property 'lookup' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to set multiple views in Nodejs(expressjs) app.

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315351/multiple-view-paths-on-node-js-express)

I got this error when run `node server` command in terminal.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'lookup' of undefined`

in this line

`var lookupProxy = express.view.lookup;`

What is wrong with my code! here is my server.js:

```
var express           = require('express');
var app                 = express();
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');


enableMultipleViewFolders(express);
app.set('views', [__dirname + '/admin/views', __dirname + '/client/views']);
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.listen(port, function(){
      console.log('Listening on port ' + port); //Listening on port 8888
});

  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
  });


  app.get('/partials/:name', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.name);
    res.render('partials/' + req.params.name);
  });


  function enableMultipleViewFolders(express) {
    // proxy function to the default view lookup
    var lookupProxy = express.view.lookup;

    express.view.lookup = function (view, options) {
        if (options.root instanceof Array) {
            // clones the options object
            var opts = {};
            for (var key in options) opts[key] = options[key];

            // loops through the paths and tries to match the view
            var matchedView = null,
                roots = opts.root;
            for (var i=0; i<roots.length; i++) {
                opts.root = roots[i];
                matchedView = lookupProxy.call(this, view, opts);
                if (matchedView.exists) break;
            }
            return matchedView;
        }

        return lookupProxy.call(express.view, view, options)
    };
 }
```

Comment: Looks again at your reference link. You are passing the wrong object to the enableMultipleViewFolders function. According to this answer and in combination with your code you should write `enableMultipleViewFolders(express);` and not to pass the `app`

Comment: Your express module does not have a view property. From what I saw in your reference link, the answer is for express version 2. I assume you are using version 4. You might be able to get a view prototype from app.get('view') instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because the express module for Express 4 has no `view` property.

To fix the issue, you need to remove the custom function for enabling multiple views. This is because Express 4 already supports multiple views. See this issue: [multiple view folders for Express](https://github.com/expressjs/express/pull/2320)