# How do you render when organising project by feature?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have changed the structure of my project and now I group stuff by features. Instead of putting all routes in "Routes", all controllers in "controllers", etc.

I find the new way much better but I have found that for rendering the local file, as it is not anymore in the "views" folder, I have to do:

`res.render("../auth/login");`// presumably we are in views so we go up and then auth/login.ejs

And inside login.ejs I have to do:

```
<%include ../views/partials/header %>
```

Is this the way to follow when using project structure by feature?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple View paths on Node.js + Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315351/multiple-view-paths-on-node-js-express)

Answer (score 0):

The folder [express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) uses for templates is called *views*, and is enabled by default:

```
app.set('views', './views'); //this code runs when you call: var app = express();
```

If you want to set multiple locations that express will look for *views*, you can do so by calling:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/foo');
```

Now, express will look in the `views` and `foo` folders for templates to use.

If you want to set multiple folders, you can call `app.set` multiple times, or simply pass an array of folders to `app.set`:

```
app.set('views', [__dirname + '/foo', __dirname + '/bar']);
```

Now, express will look in the `views`, `foo`, and `bar` folders for templates.

Lets say you have `foo.ejs` in the `foo` folder and `bar.ejs` in the `bar` folder.  You can access these templates like this:

```
<%- include 'foo' %>

<%- include 'bar' %>
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315351/multiple-view-paths-on-node-js-express) question was a good reference for your problem.

Comment: Oh I think I understand what you are saying now.  Are you trying to change the folder you keep your ejs templates in?

Comment: @JavierGuzman I added an update to my question.  I hope this helps!

Comment: I thought there would be another way but I will do it as you mention! Thanks Jane