# How to set multiple views folder in Express.js app

Tags: node.js, express

When  I have one views folder specified it will serve files, but when I specify a second alongside it does not work.  I have tried numerous things, to no avail.  Here is my code:

`app.use(express.static('views'));`

`//app.set('views', [__dirname + '/views', __dirname + '/views/views2']);`

`app.use("/views", express.static(__dirname + "/views"));`

`app.use("/views2", express.static(__dirname + "/views2"));`

The app.set doesn't work at all and so I commented it out here, and the last two lines are not working either.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  The `views` folders normally used as a default place to look for templates which does not look like what you're trying to do.  So, please describe exactly what you want this code to do.  Show input request URLs and show what file you want to be served for that URL and where that file is in your file system.  Then, if you want more than one location in the file system, show examples of both.

Comment: In the folders I do have ejs templates so I'm basically just trying to have access to multiple folders containing my ejs files.  For example my home page gets its ejs (template) and css files from the 'views' folder but I want to know how I can have multiple folders (directories) that can serve these files.  This is the line of code that gives my app access to my views, but everytime I try to add a new line with a different directory name, the app fails to look it up `app.use(express.static('views'));`

Comment: Well `express.static()` has nothing at all to do with calls to `res.render()` to render a template.  You pass `res.render()` a filename that is either an absolute path or is relative to the directory you set with `app.set('views', someDir)`.  As best I know, the template system does not have the ability to look in multiple places.  You could set a parent directory for `app.set('views', someDir)` and then use `res.render('views1/someView.ejs')` and `res.render('views2/someOtherView.ejs')` to access the other directory.  Or you can construct full paths to pass `res.render()`.

Comment: `express.static()` is for automatically rendering static HTML files (not templates).

Comment: hmmm well it works in serving my EJS files which are effectively HTML.

Comment: Well, I still can't tell what problem you're trying to solve so I'll bow out of this discussion then.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone curious about a resolution to the question: the "multiple view folders" feature is supported by the framework since Express 4.10. Express versions prior to 4.10 do NOT support setting multiple view folders. A more thorough explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315351/multiple-view-paths-on-node-js-express#:%7E:text=The%20multiple%20view%20folders%20feature%20is%20supported%20by,app.set%20(%27views%27,%20_dirname%20+%20%27%2FviewsFolder1%27,%20__dirname%20+%20%27%2FviewsFolder2%27%5D);)