# Express.js need help serving a file

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Alright, so I am trying to serve a `ejs` file to be rendered. This file is inside a different directory, so when I try to write that path it still doesn't work.  Here is the problematic code:

```
app.get('/views2/personal-form', (req, res) => {
    res.render('/views2/personal-form');
});
```

My `ejs` page is inside the folder views2 inside of the folder views. So as an example all of these following routes minus the one listed above are served:

```
app.get('/back-home', (req, res) => {
    res.render('back-home');
});
app.get('/business', (req, res) => {
    res.render('business')
});
app.get('/account', (req, res) => {
    res.render('account');
})
app.get('/personal-form', (req, res) => {
    res.render('personal-form')
});
```

I have tried putting the line of code with `personal-form` in it in numerous places and to no avail.  Any recommendations/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  In the picture, you can see the two 'views' folders.  I just want to be able to serve view files from multiple view directories so I can organize my app better.

[image: Pic of folders in VS Code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok never-mind I just got it.

`app.get('/personal-form', (req, res) => { res.render('views2/personal-form') });`

Comment: Which is exactly what I recommended in my comment [here on your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625507/how-to-set-multiple-views-folder-in-express-js-app).  Glad you figured it out.